# Спецификация C# 6.0, 7.0

Tags: c#

Попытался найти спецификацию на конструкцию `nameof()` и с удивлением обнаружил, что на C# 6.0 отсутствует официальная спецификация, которая для предыдущих версий поставлялась вместе с Visual Studio. В VS2017 файл спецификации в наличии на привычном месте, но это спецификация для C# 5.0. Есть [черновик для 6.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/), но насколько можно ему верить? А то, как бы, уже активно используется C# 7.0, а из источников информации только MSDN, на котором, традиционно, информация не совсем полная и без подробностей, плюс SO и разношёрстные форумы. Где брать достоверную информацию? Или как обычно реверс с надеждой, что ни чего не поменяют в ближайшем обновлении?

---

Про `nameof()` я все уже выяснил, это к вопросу не относится.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/64

Comment: @Zufir и? тот же вопрос и ссылки на тот же черновик, который у меня в вопросе. То что черновик может оказаться спекой к 7.0 вместо заявленного 6.0 скорее минус чем плюс, по нему и так искать не удобно, а тут еще надо не забыть что анонсировали в 6, а что в 7. Ни чего личного, естественно это не к вам претензия, просто по ссылке те же страдания, но на другом языке, я таких еще пару найти успел на разных ресурсах разной давности... Т.е. можно считать, что с тех пор ничего не поменялось? Что ж, досадно, ну ладно стандарта нет, это сейчас почти норма, но хотя бы спеки актуализировали бы

Comment: там приведено письмо C# Program Manager'а. Не сильно старое, в общем-то. Февраль. ECMA ещё не утвердила стандарт C# 5.0. То, что не утвердила ECMA стандартом и спецификацией называть нельзя. Драфт, документация, всё что угодно. Но не спецификация и не стандарт. Стандартизируют 5.0 - начнут натягивать на этот стандарт 6.0. Потом 7.0. Когда? TBD: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm Версия 5.0 вышла в 2012 году, стандартизируют её в 2018. К счастью, разрыв между 2.0 и 5.0 по функционалу мягко говоря больше, чем между 5.0 и 7.0. Поэтому будем надеяться на лучшее.

Comment: @Zufir, спецификацией можно назвать любую техническую документацию, и ECMA здесь не при чем. А вот стандарт обычно одобряется некой международной организацией, будь то ECMA, ISO, W3C, ГОСТ, и т.п. что больше нравится.